# I am doing a Survival Analysis, using R on patients survival in an intensive care. What is the correct procedure for data preparation?

Tags: r, survival, kaplan-meier

I have collected, and still am, data on survival in an intensive care. In essence, I have collected demographics, say, age, gender etc, and length of stay in the Unit, and outcome, namely died or alive.

```
 head(admissions %>% dplyr::select(LOS, Survivor, Age, Gender))
  LOS Survivor Age Gender
1  39    FALSE  72  Woman
2   5     TRUE  72  Woman
3   2     TRUE  60  Woman
4   9     TRUE  61    Man
5   5     TRUE  61    Man
6   8     TRUE  46    Man
```

I am then doing the following:

```
> fit <- survfit(Surv(admissions$LOS, admissions$Survivor) ~ admissions$Gender , data = admissions)
> print(fit)
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(admissions$LOS, admissions$Survivor) ~ 
admissions$Gender, data = admissions)

                         n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
admissions$Gender=Man   74     39     30      12      36
admissions$Gender=Woman 24     18      8       6      NA
```

I am having trouble understanding this: Events are the deaths, or the transfers?  The median would be 50% mortality at 30 days for males, and at 8 days for females? This is rather counterintuitive in this scenario.

Could this be due to patients being censored because they are discharged alive?

Should I restrict analysis to 28 days, as otherwise, my followup period will not be constant throughout?

I am trying hard to look for answers online, if you have good references, would appreciate it

Thanks

stephen

Comment: How are you proposing to use the data analysis? Just to summarize results, or to examine how certain variables might be associated with shorter survival? Note that coding-specific questions are off topic here; look at the manual page for `Surv` to see how "TRUE" is interpreted for your event values `admissions$Survivor`. Questions about statistical issues in survival analysis are on topic here.

Comment: Thanks. I am fine with the coding, I hope. I was not sure on how to prepare the data, as my KM curves were coming out weird. I was using length of stay in the ward, but this meant that I had a lot of censored data. Hence, now I have gathered the survival rate at 28 days, and used a follow up of 28 days. This means that now I have another column, rather than LOS, being FU, being maximum 28 days if the patient is alive, and less if 28 days have not yet passed, or patient died before.

Comment: The way you show your code, the R software will interpret events as censoring, and vice-versa. That’s why I referred you to the manual page. Unlike say in Matlab, TRUE  or 1 is interpreted as a death/event not as alive/censored. Please check that you are coding the events properly, see if there are still problems with your KM curves etc, and edit your question to address still-unresolved problems.